# Auto batch-insert track numbers in iTunes?

Tags: itunes

I recently imported a whole bunch of MP3s that I've already grouped into a single album, but the ID3 tags for track numbers are all blank. How can I tell iTunes to auto-add track numbers in the order they just happen to be in in iTunes? The actual order of the MP3s isn't essential, but I like to keep every MP3 in my library properly labelled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

iTunes doesn't offer this functionality natively: [Doug's AppleScripts for iTunes](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/) always comes in handy in these situations. In this case, however, there's no easy solution, because there is no script that does that. You would need a combination of three scripts, which should work and should be fairly easy as soon as you have installed all three of them:

1. Get [Number Song Names by Play Order](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=numbersongsplayorder) and run it on the tracks you would like to number. This will add track numbers to the beginning of the track name.
2. Run [Put Track Prefix to Track Numbers](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=trackprefixtonumber) on the tracks, which will set the track tags based on the number you've added in step 1.
3. Use [Remove n Characters From Front or Back](http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=removenchars) to remove the track numbers added to the name.

As far as I can tell this is the easiest way to accomplish that. Of course you could also write your own AppleScript which does it in one step. And don't forget to create a backup, just in case.

Answer (score 2):

A script to increment the track numbers in the order in which they appear is now available at Doug's Apple Scripts. I have tried it and it works famously...

http://dougscripts.com/itunes/scripts/ss.php?sp=incrementnumbertags